# Android Studio on Linux - not able to run a virtual device

Tags: java, android, linux

I was programming in Android Studio on Windows using an Intel Processor for about 1,5 years. Due to my switch to AMD Ryzen, i'm not able to run a virtual device on Windows cause of it's need of Intel HAXM. That's why I switched to Linux, more accurate to Ubuntu 16.4.
I spent a lot of time searching for answers, assured myself to have KVW running, installed the latest Java version (which was quite difficult for a Linux beginner) and Android Studio is working fine, however I'm not able to run a virtual device. The gradle build finishes quite fast, however the Virtual Device won't come online.

Does anyone have the same problem and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get if you run `~/Android/Sdk/tools/sdk/tools/emulator -accel-check`? taken from here - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html Instructions how to configure are at the bottom of that page.